# Is it possible to create generic overrides using Reflections?

Tags: c#, logging, reflection

We're currently trying to figure out how to create really extended logging. so including the method call stack, method parameters, values, everything.

to do that we're basically using reflections. we have a factory method creating an instance and then comes the dirty point.
we're creating this instance using string concatenated c# code.

the target is to append the logging code before and after the executed function in the context while having access to the type signature

i personally would rather like something like this:

```cs
public class LoggingWrapper<T> : T{
    public LoggingWrapper(){
        var virtualMethodsOfT = /* Do Reflection magic here */;
        foreach(var method in virtualMethodsOfT){
            this.CreateOverrideFunction(method.Name, ()=> LoggingOutline(method.BaseCall));
        }
    }

    static LoggingOutline(Action baseMethod){
    // Logging Code before
    baseMethod();
    // Logging Code after
    }
}
```

to make it look sexy i'd probably also store the reflection data in a in-memory dictionary, because i heard it's awfully slow

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection? For attaching logger to functions or attach code to logger? Could you describe your purpose more descriptive?

Comment: i tried^^ all i want is to apply custom logging at the beginning and at the end of a function. i want to log the method signature like name, parameters including the parameters it has been called with. reason: error logging. a lot of exceptions have no possibility to figure out what exactly went wrong. if the method grows too long and you have a null reference exception and the method has 20 parametrs (worst case), then it's impossible to find out what actually happened. 


btw it should be a replacement for fody... because we're using that a.t.m

Comment: the important point is that i want to have the same code in every service i'm injecting. without needing to plug it manually in every method. this is why i want to have some kind of "wrapper" which overrides the function and adds code before and after.